# bsearch wrapper

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, c++11

I was just toying with search algorithms a while ago and after a few benchmarks, I was impressed to see how much faster the old bsearch() was comparend to std::binary_search(). I thought that any decent compiler would be able to replace std::binary_search() by bsearch() when possible, but even though I'm using GCC 4.7, bsearch seems to perform something like 5 times faster than std::binary_search.

So I thought that it would be a great exercise trying to create some kind of wrapper for bsearch with the same interface then std::binary_search. But for an unknown reason, I did not manage to do it. Here's my code:

```
template<typename InputIterator, class T>
bool binary_search(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, const T& value)
{
    auto cmp = [](const void* a, const void* b)
    {
        return (int) ((*(T*)a) == (*(T*)b));
    };

    std::cout << value << std::endl;
    T* res = (T*) bsearch(&value, first, last-first, sizeof(*first), cmp);
    return res != nullptr;
}
```

The code compiles fine and does not crash at execution. However, it seems that bsearch stops right after one internal iteration (*res is always equals to the value at the middle of the tab passed as parameter). I can't manage to find why it does not work. So, if possible, a little help would be fine.

Thanks.

---

For those who ask for the code used to check the speed:

```
const std::string keyword_str[] = {
    // Some strings
};

int cmp(const void* s1, const void* s2)
{
    return (int) ((*(std::string*)s1) == (*(std::string*)s2));
}

int main()
{
    time_t start, end;
    double dif;
    time (&start);

    // Code
    for (const string& str: keyword_str)
    {
        for (size_t i = 0 ; i < 1000000 ; ++i)
        {
            // std::binary_search (uncomment to check)
            //bool a = std::binary_search(keyword_str, keyword_str+28, str);

            // bsearch
            char** st = (char**) bsearch(&str, keyword_str, 28, sizeof(keyword_str[0]), cmp);
        }
    }

    time (&end);
    dif = difftime (end, start);
    printf("Time spent: %fs.\n", dif);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'd be interested to see your test case that demonstrates this 5x performance gap.

Comment: Those that you name `InputIterator` need to implement the `RandomAccessIterator` _concept_

Comment: It's faster because `cmp` returns `(int)false` (`== 0`) for unequal elements. When `bsearch` sees that `0`, it thinks it means "equal" and stops to search. So `bsearch` usually thinks it found the element quite quickly while `std::binary_search` does a real search.

Comment: Haha, that's so lame of me now you say it. I'll change that right now. It would be easier to use if there was some spaceshift operator in C++.

Comment: It is usually the other way around. `std::sort` and `std::binary_search` should be *faster* than the C functions `qsort` and `bsearch` because the templated C++ algorithms can inline the comparisons (assuming you used a comparator type rather than a comparison function), instead of calling out to external function as in the C functions

Comment: If your compiler reports anything else than `0`, then it is doing something wrong: the result of the searches not being used, the call should be discarded, and then the loop not executed altogether. Those functions are unfortunately not correctly annotated as `__pure__` I guess :x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bsearch` takes a function pointer, and `cmp` is not a function pointer. (**EDIT:** I was wrong about this. Since `cmp` doesn't capture any variables -- it's brackets are empty -- it can be passed as a function pointer. This behavior is specified in §5.1.2/6 of the C++11 standard.)

`bsearch` also doesn't return the right values that the comparison function is expected to return. It should return -1 if the key is less than the array element, 0 if they are equal, and 1 if the key is greater than the array element. Your `cmp` function returns 0 if they are inequal and 1 if they are equal. As a result, if the first element you're comparing is inequal to the key, then your `cmp` makes `bsearch` think they're equal and `bsearch` stops because it thinks it found the right element immediately.

Comment: Oh, now you say it, I remember how wrong I am for the bsearch function. I did not know for the type of the cmp function though. Since I did not have any compilation error or anything, I just assumed the type was the right one.

Answer (score 2):

In general, it is not possible to use `bsearch` to implement `std::binary_search` because `bsearch` can only search a contiguous array of elements, whereas `std::binary_search` works on a range of iterators, for any iterator type. It could be a linked list iterator, a deque iterator, or some custom, exotic iterator that the user created. There is obviously no way to search these iterators with `bsearch`